# Append a file, output to screen and redirect from stderr all at once, without tee

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, busybox, tee

I'm running a `time dd` command in a shell script, and I'd like to output the results to a file, and print it out on the screen. The line that I'm currently running is:

```
(time dd of=$dest_filepath if=$src_filepath bs=$block_size count=$block_count) >> $log_file 2>&1 &
```

Although that is leaving me with an empty file and doesn't output to screen. What would I need to do in order to do all three things?

Note that I'm running this in an embedded system with a Busybox installation which **does not include `tee`** so this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80707/how-to-output-text-to-both-screen-and-file-inside-a-shell-script/80708#80708).

Comment: Have you looked for  `man tee`

Comment: Why don't you have `tee`? What OS are you using? What output do you expect in your file? The `time` or the `dd` or both?

Comment: It's a cut down version of Linux running on busybox. I don't have it because of how cut down the version was - I didn't have bash until I explicitly enables it and rebuilt. I'm expecting both time and dd to output to file. @terdon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're showing works as expected on my system. Are you sure you're using `bash` and not `sh`? In any case, I tried with `dash` and with `busybox`'s `sh` and it worked there too. In the absence of `tee`, I think the only solution will be to `cat $logfile` after the command is finished.

Another possibility would be to make a link to `busybox` called `tee` and attempt to run that. The `busybox` that came with my Debian supports that but I don't know if yours will:

```
ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/tee
```

Then, try running `tee` normally.

If you really can't get `tee`, your only other option would be something like this:

```
foo=$( ( time dd if="file1" of="file2" bs=12 count=5 ) 2>&1 &)
echo "$foo"
echo "$foo" >> logfile
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `cat`ing it is really a viable option, as I'm running the command thousands of times, so catting the file would print all of the outputs every time.

Comment: @Yann4 did you try linking to `busybox` as `tee`? In any case, you're working with a minimal system, you can expect some loss of functionality. If you can't get `tee` to work, there's no way around catting. The only other choice would be to save the output as a variable, echo it and then print it to the file.

Comment: It's not on the system, I'd have to recompile the kernel to get it there.

Comment: The Busybox shipped by Debian includes most utilities with most features. It isn't a reliable indicator of what might be found in Busybox instances on very small systems. A lot of things are optional when you compile Busybox. If the tee utility had been included, the `tee` command would presumably exist already. For example, my router's Busybox has 97 utilities, while Debian's has 200.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `tee` command. Here i have grouped the commands `time` and `dd` using the code block so that they will be treated as a single command and their output can be handled easily.

```
{ time dd of=$dest_filepath if=$src_filepath bs=$block_size count=$block_count; } 2>&1|tee $log_file
```

Make note of the `;` at the end of the second command. This is mandatory for code blocks to work.

Incase if you dont want to use `tee` then you might think about this

```
{ time dd of=$dest_filepath if=$src_filepath bs=$block_size count=$block_count; } 2>&1 &> $log_file;cat $log_file
```

Comment: I explicitly said in the question that I needed to do it without `tee`

Comment: why cant you create a symbolic link of busybox pointing to tee for this purpose ?

Comment: How about `tail -f $log_file` ?

Comment: @KannanMohan Creating a symlink is highly unlikely to help. If tee had been included in that busybox executable, there should be a symlink for it already.