# Perl Script Output in Excel / Text file in Solaris 10

Tags: shell-script, perl

I have a perl script, I am not able to get output of script in an excel or text file format. Can someone please help me figure out that ?

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '
    opendir D, "." || die "open .: $!\n";
    for (sort grep {!/^.{1,2}\z/} readdir D) {
if (@s = lstat$) {
printf("%-58s %s %s\n", $_,
map {strftime("%d-%m-%y", localtime $)} ($s[9], $s[8]))
} else {warn "$: $!\n"}
 }'
```

Comment: Hello, if you want any help, could you please format your script in a readable way with line jump for example. Also could please explain what you want to do in excel ? text files are quiet easilly importable in excel without to much work. What is not working.

Comment: Hi, I want output of script to produce on text files, Currently it's displaying result on screen, I want output in text file.

Comment: please [edit] your question to add any relevant information to your question. and in this case it invole formatting your code to make it understandable.

Comment: your question has been answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80707/53092

Comment: Akki, "_it's displaying result on screen, I want output in text file_". That's called a redirection (`>`). Asking the author of this script might have been faster.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas, Request your help here.

Comment: Hi Thanks roaima and TNT, I have done the redirection and got desired output in .txt file. @TNT, I wasn't able to execute perl -w because perl command was clashing with another perl command in script.

Answer (score 2):

save the script above in a file call it `myscript.pl` and run it un terminal as:

```
perl -w myscript.pl > /output_folder/my_output.txt
```

Comment: Just be careful, as the script appears to read the current directory for input filenames, so saving the output to the current directory *may* be confusing.