# Shell command output to file with command being executed

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

How can I output the command itself in addition to its output to a file?

I know that I can do [how to output text to both screen and file inside a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80707/24192) to capture the output. My use case is specific to pytest.

```
pytest /awesome_tests -k test_quick_tests -n auto &> test_output_$(date -u +"%FT%H%MZ").txt
```

It would be really helpful to have the command executed in the output so I knew specifically what the results were for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using bash soley for the `&>` redirection that you started with, but sh-compatible otherwise:

```sh
set -- '/awesome_tests' '-k' 'test_quick_tests' '-n' 'auto'
{ printf '%s %s\n' 'pytest' "$*";
  pytest "$@";
} &> test_output_$(date -u +"%FT%H%MZ").txt
```

This sets up the positional parameters to contain the arguments to the `pytest` command; it then runs two commands inside the `{}` brace grouping:

1. print the `pytest` string followed by the concatenation of the arguments by space (the default first character of `$IFS`)
2. run the actual `pytest` command with the given arguments

That brace group is then redirected as before.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh -v <<< 'pytest /awesome_tests -k test_quick_tests -n auto' \
    &> test_output_$(date -u +"%FT%H%MZ").txt
```

`sh -v` causes `sh` to echo each command line to `stderr`, so since you're already capturing `stderr` to your output file, all that is needed is to use the `-v` option and to supply `sh` with the command you wish to run.

Note that in my testing, `sh -v -c 'your-command-here'` did not work.

```
echo 'pytest /awesome_tests -k test_quick_tests -n auto' | \
    sh -v &> test_output_$(date -u +"%FT%H%MZ").txt
```

does work, but `echo ... |` is what `bash`'s `<<<` is for.

Comment: `sh -v -c` probably did not work since the shell had already read the commands (since you used `-c`). The `-v` makes the shell output the commands "as they are read".

Comment: @Kusalananda Yep.  Just checked the man page and that is exactly it.